# having trouble disabling/re-enabling javascript webui-popover

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using this script here: https://github.com/sandywalker/webui-popover

I'm initializing a popover on an element but wanting to disable it under certain circumstances. I want to then re-enable it, but my code is not working

You can see it here: http://jsfiddle.net/z613fsnu/1/

```
function enablePopover() {           
    $('#popover').webuiPopover();
}
function disablePopover() {
    $('#popover').webuiPopover().off();
}
$('#enable').click(function() {
    enablePopover();
});
$('#disable').click(function() {
    disablePopover();
});

<a href="#" id="enable">enable</a>
<a href="#" id="disable">disable</a>
<a href="#" id="popover">popover</a>
```

Calling enablePopover() does indeed enable it. Calling disablePopover() then disables it. But then if I call enablePopover() again after disablePopover() it does not re-initialize the popover.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: do you get any errors on the page when you try to enablePopover again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use  `$('#glossary_btn').webuiPopover('destroy');`

http://jsfiddle.net/9kmt2q6v/

**HTML:**

```
<a href="#" id="glossary_btn">glossary btn</a>
<br/><br/>
<a id="on">ON</a>
<br/><br/>
<a id="off">OFF</a>
```

**JQ:**

```
function enablePopover() {       
    $('#glossary_btn').webuiPopover({title:'Title',content:'Content',placement:'right'});
}

function disablePopover() {
    $('#glossary_btn').webuiPopover('destroy');
}

$('#off').click(function(){
    disablePopover()
})

$('#on').click(function(){
    enablePopover()
})
```